# What thread to use in tapping a hole for a 2-56 Helicoil insert?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Helicoil from McMaster-Carr [18-8 Stainless Steel Helical Inserts 91732A201](https://www.mcmaster.com/catalog/124/3382)  calls out a specific tap to use, but I cannot find out what thread this tap is putting into the hole for the insert.  I want to call out the tapped thread on a drawing, and put the 2-56 insert in later.
I cannot find what the thread should be.  This would be the outside thread of the helicoil.  I know the drill size is #41 = 0.0960 but what is the thread size?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check if the add link is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Helicoil taps are what's known as "STI" or "Screw Thread Insert" Taps. They have the same pitch as the fastener that they're going to be used with, but a larger outer diameter, to account for the wire going into the space between.

In my personal experience, the hole callout on a drawing should indicate the size of the fastener to be inserted into that hole, for example: "M10x1.5 STI".

This matches the way that the taps themselves are labelled and [sold](https://www.cromwell.co.uk/shop/cutting-tools/thread-repair/helicoil-metric-hand-taps%3A-bottoming/f/13447?query=helicoil%20taps), with the fastener thread indicated.
 [image: image of coil forming tap]

Comment: Thanks Jonathan!  That makes sense.  I did not realize "STI" defined the thread type.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to click the 'accept as answer' button if this answered your question - otherwise the 'community' bot auto-bumps this question in a few months' time, which buries other new questions.